# What is the correct usage of "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" in ASP.NET MVC2/3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-4.0, iis-7.5

I've read various posts and questions about the use of `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` in the `modules` section of `<system.WebServer>` and I'm concerned that I'm using this setting incorrectly.

All my ASP.NET MVC applications are written using .NET Framework 4.0 and MVC2, plus we have a beta of an application that uses MVC3.

These apps are deployed to servers running Windows 2008R2/IIS7.5. The sites are configured to run in Integrated Pipeline/.NET 4.0 application pools.

If I set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"` then I get a HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error from IIS. If I set this to true then all is well.

However [this article](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html) suggests this is a bad thing to do and a fix:

> Don't use runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" when getting your MVC routing to work

Is it really that bad, should I follow this advice?

Comment: Microsoft came out with a hotfix (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368) if you don't want to set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`.

Comment: @Ek0nomik - Yeah...and I know all about that hotfix :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078459 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080837 . I even got a KB raised about the problems it caused: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2620604

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for sending along your research.  I never use the Web.config for setting page specific authorization (I only use authorization attributes), so I haven't had any issues with the hotfix.

Comment: @Ek0nomik - those issues were related to classic ASP and ASP.NET Forms apps that the 980368 QFE broke, not MVC. MVC was fine. As a web hoster it caused us a headache or two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How bad it is depends on the site traffic, if you are working on a high traffic website I'd say don't use it, and remove unneeded modules.

Comment: Having mulled this over for a day you're right. Fortunately most of the stuff I'm doing at the moment doesn't attract a massive amount of minute by minute traffic.