# ASP.NET Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, asp.net-4.0

I have the following ASP.NET Forms Authentication configuration:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="MembershipCookie" 
           loginUrl="Login.aspx" 
           protection="All" 
           timeout="525600" 
           slidingExpiration="true" 
           enableCrossAppRedirects="true" 
           path="/">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="Home.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location
```

If an anonymous user visits the site and requests `home.aspx` should they be denied access and kicked to the `Login.aspx` page because the first rule `<deny users="?" />` will match and further processing will stop?

The site is running on IIS7.5, ASP.NET 4.0 and the application pool is configured for Integrated Pipeline mode.

**Update:**

The reason for this question was to sanity check my understanding of ASP.NET 4.0's Forms Authentication behaviour (which was actually correct). There is a related follow up question which describes what looks like a bug in a hotfix (which is also rolled into Windows 2008R2 SP1) - KB980368:

> [ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0 seem to treat the root url differently in Forms Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080837/asp-net-2-0-and-4-0-seem-to-treat-the-root-url-differently-in-forms-authenticatio)

Comment: Check out http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx

Comment: @JAngwenyi - thanks for the link, I thought that's what should happen. The question was a sanity check, see my latest post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080837

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an user is accessing Home.aspx , it will use the configuration section for Home.aspx specified by `<location />` and hence the user will not be kicked out to Login.aspx .

Answer (score 2):

If a user access Home.aspx then the second rule will be applied i.e.

```
<location path="Home.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

**The point to note here is:** `*` tells that **any authorized user** (having any or no role assigned) could access the page, but `?` tells **unauthorized user** could not access the page.