# How do I redirect users to an error page if their username is not stored in the database? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, authorization

What I would like to do is if a user is not stored in the database yet, then they should be redirected to another site (say Google for now). The issue is, I can't use response.redirect in my catch {} block. What happens is if the user is not in role, then an error page that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." With the stack trace included. This is the code I have in my authorization class:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        try
        {
            if (securityDB.Database.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                securityDB.Database.Connection.Open();
            }

            USER user = securityDB.USERs
            .Where(o => o.USER_NAME == username)
            .FirstOrDefault();

            var roles = from ur in user.USER_ROLE
                        from r in securityDB.ROLEs
                        where ur.ROLE_ID == r.ID
                        select r.ROLE_NAME;
            if (roles != null)
                return roles.ToArray();
            else

                return new string[] { }; ;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Reroute user to www.google.com
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        //return new string[] { };

    }
```

Comment: _"if a user is not stored in the database yet"_ - I think you're missing `if (user != null)` as `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if there aren't any matches in the DB.

Comment: Suggestion: this method should not attempt to do any http redirection. It's title is `GetRolesForUser`. That's all it should do - return the list of roles for a give user or throw an exception if it can't find said user. Make another method that you call first to check if the user exists, and use the result to do the redirection.

Comment: I wouldn't use an exception at all for this. It is a normal and expected condition and I have read that exceptions can be heavy and slow. With the improvement 
suggested by @stuartd , perhaps you can return a tuple of Boolean, List<string>. Then the calling code can simply check the Boolean and if false redirect and ignore the list completely.

Comment: the functionality you are looking this can help refer this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719517/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-if-user-directly-entres-url-in-browser-using-asp-n)