# Problem with Default Document and IIS7.5/Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, sitecore, windows-7-x64

I'm having a problem with a component used in a Sitecore solution on our Windows 7 workstations that is driving me batty.

In short, the component in question adds `<script>` tags to the page that load supporting JavaScript files. The `src` attributes are set to something like:

```
/path/to/scriptgenerator/?r=1234&p=asdf
```

Those paths are not working - I'm getting a 404 back.

You might thing "oh ... well, the path doesn't exist." But it does, and it also has a Default.aspx page in it. In fact, if I try the following path, the JS is generated and returned by the server:

```
/path/to/scriptgenerator/Default.aspx?r=1234&p=asdf
```

We're testing the site using IIS7.5, not Visual Studio's debugging web server. Of course, on the production machines, which are Win Server 2008, things work just fine.

The component in question is a third-party component and I have no access to the source code, so I can't just modify it to append default.aspx to the SRC path.

I have checked to verify that Default.aspx is set up as a default document for the site, and it is.

I tried to work around the problem using ISAPI_Rewrite, but for some reason, rules that I set up for /path/to/scriptgenerator are ignored.

I've tried the solution described in these questions, and that has no effect on my problem:
[IIS 7 Not Serving Default Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948669/iis-7-not-serving-default-document)
[ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0 seem to treat the root url differently in Forms Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080837/asp-net-2-0-and-4-0-seem-to-treat-the-root-url-differently-in-forms-authenticatio)

I'm really not sure what to try or look for next ... any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you're using webforms, not MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this component set up within the same IIS Site as the Sitecore application?

If so, have you added path `/path/to/scriptgenerator` to `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` setting in `web.config`?

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I'll know to look for that in the future.