# IIS 7.5 Not serving Default Document in Integrated pipeline mode?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-7.5, virtual-directory, integrated-pipeline-mode

**Before change:**

I have website `local.Mywebsite.com` hosted in my Local IIS 7.5.The website is running in *.net version 4.0* and IIS app pool is in **Integrated pipeline mode**. It is working perfectly fine.

I am able to Browse the **local.Mywebsite.com/default.aspx** as **local.Mywebsite.com** It means IIS serving the default document as i configured.

**The Change:**

I had a requirement to include another application **Foo** to My website as virtual directory.I added that and am able to Browse and use the same with complete path as **local.Mywebsite.com/Foo/Mypage.aspx**.

Then i configured a default document for my **Foo** virtual directory.

**MY issue:**

I try to browse to **local.Mywebsite.com/Foo/**

I got an error:

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies)
could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  
Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

Now IIS is not serving default document for my **Foo** virtual directory.

But still am able to browse **local.Mywebsite.com**, IIS serves default document here.

Any one have any idea or any suggestions are highly appreciated.

**Update:**

When i **Rename** the file **Mypage.aspx** in to **Default.aspx**, then IIS serves the default document pretty fine. Am able to see the **default.aspx** page by browsing **local.Mywebsite.com/Foo/**.

My Web config:

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <clear/>
    <add value="Mypage.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Comment: i had check this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948669/iis-7-not-serving-default-document but this is for `classical pipeline mode`

Comment: Can you post the relevant web.config section for `/Foo`?

Comment: Also you've used two incorrect spellings of `default.aspx` : **deafualt.aspx**  and **defualt.aspx**, are these just typo's in your question?

Comment: @Kev thanks for time spelling is corrected in my question and this was not the issue.Which config section are you expecting ?

Comment: You've still got the spelling wrong :) **defualt.aspx** -> **default.aspx**. The default document config section is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried to clear your browsing data? it could also be the reason.

Comment: @bot i had already tried by clearing my browsing data

Answer (score 1):

It gives 404 error when you are running the application in debug mode on your machine.

1.Please verify in your web.config that you have the following set-up

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>

  <identity impersonate="true"/>

  <authorization>

  <allow users="*"/>

</authorization>
```

I have a similar problem before and adding `<identity impersonate="true"/>` solve it.

2.Make sure you have a correct version of .NET selected in IIS(which in your case is .NET 4.0)
3.This also occur if you don't have a start page set under your web project's properties
4.Try also to clear your browsing data. Especially when you are using IE.

If the error still shows, set custom error mode off in the web.config so that you will see where the real problem is coming 
and you could sort it out. :)

Comment: This will not solved my issue. Am using `form authentication`. I had already checked all thing what you are mentioned here. Thanks for your time ;)